# Default google search country

Tags: chrome-for-android, search, google-search

I am normally fairly astute at being able to change settings etc, however, I have hit a problem I cannot overcome and thought to ask here:

In android chrome, when I perform a search the searches (as of Wednesday) are all performed in google.nl and the results are returned in English.  This means the results are more appropriate for someone living in the Netherlands and not in the UK.  I was wondering how I change the default search location as I cannot find it in Android at all (My PC based Chrome works as normal, and I can change that quite straightforwardly).

Would love to know how to set the default google search location for chrome back to google.com or google.co.uk.

All assistance gratefully accepted!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is no simple way that also preserves open tabs etc...
The only way I have found to do it, through trial and error is to go to **Settings > apps> chrome** and clear all data, then when you -rerun chrome it sets the default search locale back to the country you are in.

Comment: The search locale though isn't defined by your phone. It's defined by what location Google thinks your accessing their Web application from.

Comment: The google site used stayed as google.nl for me regardless of what country I was in according to GPS and router information: I connected through systems in the UK, France, Netherlands and Switzerland. and the site never moved from the NL google site, I even had GPS forced to provide different locations to suit the IP address my browser was returning, and it did not help, in the end only what I did above worked.  In theory I could have done some low level editing to change it however wanted to see how it worked from a standard user point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, you are able to use the 3 dots menu, navigate to settings, click on search engine and choose your preferred search engine, in this case. Google.

mine reads as google.com, location allowed. (which is clickable), clicking on the location allowed, provides a settings page which allows you to clear and reset permissions as well as alter permissions individually.

@user145490 does make a good point, if you are using a VPN or something similar, the locale is set by the network, irrespective of GPS.